# Accessing the $root binding context within a knockout.js component template

Tags: knockout.js

Accessing the $root binding context in the template of a KO component returns the view model of the page instead of the component's view model. Why is this and how can I access the component's view model from within a nested binding context without using $parent?

The following example snippets output "test2".

HTML:

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

JS:

```
ko.components.register("my-component", {
    template: "<div data-bind='text: $root.test'></div>",
    viewModel: function(params) { this.test = "test1" }
});

ko.applyBindings({ test: "test2" });
```

Comment: Why don't you just write `<div data-bind='text: test'></div>`?

Comment: @nemesv It was just an example to reproduce what I mean. In reality it would be a binding in a nested binding context.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Currently you cant use $root binding context as component context, but $parent and $parents[] are working as expected see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html). There will be $component binding context same as $root for page in version 3.3 and it is allready done [github](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1449).